# How to use sqlite on nodejs/express?

Tags: node.js, sqlite

```
var express = require('express'); 
var router = express.Router();
var http = require('http');
var util = require('util');

var fs = require("fs");
var file = "/usr/local/test.db";
var exists = fs.existsSync(file);
if(!exists) {
 console.log("Creating DB file.");
 fs.openSync(file, "w");
}

var sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database(file);

db.serialize(function() {
//create table if not exist
db.run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TEXT" 
    + "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,"
    + "body TEXT,"
    + "create_time INTEGER,"
    + "num_upvotes INTEGER,"
    + "num_downvotes INTEGER"
    + ")"
    );

 });

router.post('/createtext', function(req, res){
var text = req.query.text;
var now = new Date().getTime();
db.run("insert into TEXT(body, create_time, num_upvotes, num_downvotes) values(?, ?, 0, 0)", [text, now]);
res.writeHead(200)
res.end();
});

router.get('/gettexts', function(req, res){
var textId = req.query.id;
var limit = req.query.limit;
db.all('select * from TEXT where id<? order by id asc limit ?', [textId, limit],
function (err, rows){
    if (err){
        console.err(err);
        res.status(500);
    }else {
        res.json({ "data" : rows});
    }
  });
});

router.get('/gettext', function(req, res){
var textId = req.query.id;
db.all('select * from TEXT where id=?', [textId],
function (err, row){
    if (err){
        console.err(err);
        res.status(500);
    }else {
        res.json({ "data" : row});
    }
});
}); 

router.post('/upvote', function(req, res){
var textId = req.query.id;
db.run("update TEXT set num_upvotes=num_upvotes + 1 where id=?", [textId], function(err, row){
    if (err){
        console.err(err);
        res.status(500);
    }
    else {
        res.status(202);
    }
    res.end();
});
});

router.post("/downvote", function(req, res){
var textId = req.query.id;
db.run("update TEXT set num_downvotes=num_downvotes + 1 where id=?", [textId], function(err, row){
    if (err){
        console.err(err);
        res.status(500);
    }
    else {
        res.status(202);
    }
    res.end();
});
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here is the code what I use for my application. It works fine, but I want to know if there are any problem when it is going to have large traffic. I also have few questions.

1. does it handle synchronization?
2. should I put db.close() anywhere?
3. Do I need any connection pool?